# react-simple-image-slider - how to fit image to slider

Tags: css, reactjs

I am using react-simple-image slider and everything works smoothly but I dont get how to adjust the image to fit to the slider container. The documentation says this:

can customize by className with !important;

```
.your-app {
  .rsis-container {
    // do something
  }
}

.your-app {
  .rsis-image {
    background-size: contain !important;
  }
}
```

but I dont understand where to add it in my project (please see files)
[files](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZfMjE.png)

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: Add it the App.css file